# Fatal Exception: NSArchiverArchiveInconsistency: data is corrupt or value is not an object

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.Product.Staging")!
defaults.value(forKey: "PRODUCTS") != nil 
let productsData = defaults.value(forKey: "PRODUCTS") as? NSData
//CRASHES HERE ->
var products = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: productsData as Data) as? Products
//CRASHED
```

I'am saving data in UserDefaults using NSKeyedArchiver and fetching data using NSKeyedUnarchiver. While Fetching the data from NSKeyedArchiver the data shows corrupt and crashes the app. I cannot determine why this is crashing and I don't want to clear the app data too. This crash is happening only sometimes.

Comment: This code does not compile (`unarchiveObject(with` expects a non-optional). By the way: Never use `value(forKey` in `UserDefaults`. The proper method is `object(forKey` and in this case even `data(forKey`. And don't use `NS...` Foundation classes if there is a native counterpart (`NSData / Data`)

Comment: I actually want to know what has caused this error for data to be corrupt